# Which titles are included in Street Fighter 30th Anniversary Collection

Tags: version-differences, nintendo-switch, street-fighter-series

Street Fighter 30th Anniversary Collection looks like a pretty comprehensive collection, but what I can't seem to find is **a list** of the Street Fighter titles it includes.

I read that the lineup may vary depending on which region's version you buy. But again, can't seem to find any region-specific lists either. (I am mostly interested in the US and Japan versions, for Nintendo Switch.)

Specifically, I am curious whether Street Fighter EX and Street Fighter EX2 are part of the bundle. Those were 3D Playstation and Playstation 2 titles that handled really well, and introduced lots of new characters, as I recall.

Any clarification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Fighter_30th_Anniversary_Collection) has a list of the 12 games (13 for Switch) that are in the collection:

> - Street Fighter:
>
>   - Street Fighter (1987)
> - Street Fighter II:
>
>   - Street Fighter II: The World Warrior (1991)
>   - Street Fighter II: Champion Edition (1992)
>   - Street Fighter II Turbo: Hyper Fighting (1992)
>   - Super Street Fighter II: The New Challengers (1993)
>   - Super Street Fighter II: The Tournament Battle (1993, Switch exclusive)
>   - Super Street Fighter II Turbo (1994)
> - Street Fighter Alpha:
>
>   - Street Fighter Alpha: Warriors' Dreams (1995)
>   - Street Fighter Alpha 2 (1996)
>   - Street Fighter Alpha 3 (1998)
> - Street Fighter III:
>
>   - Street Fighter III: New Generation (1997)
>   - Street Fighter III: 2nd Impact (1997)
>   - Street Fighter III: 3rd Strike (1999)

The exclusive game to the Switch appears to be just *Super Street Figher II* but "[features eight-player single-elimination tournament gameplay.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Street_Fighter_II#Tournament_Battle)"  The link to the Wikipedia page for the collection also states:

> The Nintendo Switch version of the game includes an exclusive eight player tournament mode for Super Street Fighter II that can be played locally with four consoles.

Lastly, it seems the [Japanese version](https://streetfighter.fandom.com/wiki/Street_Fighter_30th_Anniversary_Collection#Development) of the collection has both the Japanese version of the individual games, plus the international ones.  According to the Fandom Wiki:

> In Japan the compilation is known as Street Fighter 30th Anniversary Collection International. In addition to the international version of each game, it also features the Japanese versions.

The Fandom Wiki originally cites this from [4GamerNet](https://www.4gamer.net/games/404/G040452/20180713015/).